# Getting error "_git:19: command not found: _default" when implementing git-completion scripts in zsh

Tags: git, zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion, git-completion

I am trying to configure my zsh terminal to use git's tab completion script.

Some of my trouble may be coming from a non-standard file structure:

```
$ tree ~/Scripts
/Users/luigi/Scripts
├── connect.sh
├── git-completion.sh
├── git-completion.zsh
├── git-prompt.sh
└── pshell_connect.sh
```

My zshrc config details for tab completion:

```
fpath=(~/Scripts $fpath)
source ~/Scripts/git-prompt.sh
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/Scripts/git-completion.sh
source ~/Scripts/git-completion.zsh
```

And again the error message when I start a session:

```
_git:19: command not found: _default
```

Am I maybe missing some additional dependencies or did I just goof up something on the configuration? I'm coming from Linux so it's probably the latter.

I have tried reading the source and I see the `_git ()` function. I am assuming the error originates from this line:

```
let _ret && _default && _ret=0
```

where the `_default ()` function is being evaluated, but I have no idea where this is supposed to be defined.

Comment: Your setup seems to be broken; `_default` is normally installed as part of zsh (packet `zsh-common` on my system, macos will vary) - does completion work for other commands? do you have `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit` in your .zshrc?

Comment: @TomRegner I can do tab completion for the normal stuff like files/directories in my path. 
I do not have that line in my .zshrc file. Where would be the appropriate location to place that?